# NameError: name 'build_ext' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.6

Trying to install `pyobjus` getting the following error:

> Collecting pyobjus>=1.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
>   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/9e/6425d66cf66892ee99ebdc86204c825d6817458328b6cdc3a6c51ad152d1/pyobjus-1.1.0.tar.gz
>   (72kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 10.7MB/s 
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/tmp/pip-build-oo0_gm_g/pyobjus/setup.py", line 58, in 
>           cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
>       NameError: name 'build_ext' is not defined

Comment: I have been facing this same issue. Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: I was facing the same issue installing a different package. I fixed it by updating my pip.